# How to use the get(int index) method of arraylist having nodes as records with data fields

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to be clarified on the use of get(int index) method to check on the record data fields of nodes in an arraylist..

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ArrayNodeDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<Object> lstObject = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setPersonId(1);
    p1.setPersonName("Tom");
    lstObject.add(p1);

    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.setPersonId(2);
    p2.setPersonName("Jerry");
    lstObject.add(p2);
```

The following code gives the node locations:

```
    System.out.println("1st record : " + lstObject.get(0));          
    System.out.println("2nd record : " + lstObject.get(1));

      }
     }
```

While, the following gets an error:

```
    System.out.println("1st record : " + lstObject.get(0).getPersonId());          
    System.out.println("2nd record : " + lstObject.get(1).getPersonId());

      }
     }
```

Comment: Why did you specify an element type of `Object`? Would you have assigned these `Person` instances to an `Object` variable and expected to have access to `getPersonId`?

Answer (score 1):

With your current `ArrayList` declaration, `lstObject.get(0)` returns an `Object` reference, and not all `Object` instances have a `getPersonId()` method (in fact, most of them don't), so the compiler doesn't allow `lstObject.get(0).getPersonId()`.

You should use the exact type you intend to put in the `ArrayList` :

```
ArrayList<Person> lstObject = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

This will let the compiler know that `lstObject.get(0)` returns a reference to a `Person`, so the compiler will allow you to call `getPersonId()` for that reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you specified the elements in the `ArrayList` as `Object`, thus Java does not know how to call `getPersonId()`. It could be any object. Just getting the object with `get()` runs fine, because there is a default method `toString()` in every class inherited from `Object`. You should declare the array as

```
ArrayList<Person> lstObject = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a few options. 
First, you can change the Object to Person in your array list declaration, or you can add a cast to Person in your Print as the following:

```
System.out.println("1st record : " + ((Person)lstObject.get(0)).getPersonId()); 
System.out.println("2nd record : " + ((Person)lstObject.get(1)).getPersonId());
```